# Slow time to first byte (TTFB) Flask with `FileSystemCache`

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, flask-caching

I'm facing slow *Time to First Byte (TTFB)* for my web app in Flask, after changing my linux server. The problem seams to show up only on the first time access or after cache expires (5 minutes). Sometimes TTFB reaches 16 seconds.

I confirmed the problem through:

1. **Gunicorn** logs (running in *debug mode* with all logs specified)
2. **Nginx** logs (using custom logging `upstream_response_time` and `request_time`)
3. Running **Flask** in development mode.

I verified the problem doesn't exist (*TTFB* of some *ms*) on the same server running for example:

1. Python [single line web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8058846/1207193)
2. [`'Hello world'`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) Flask app

Looking at **htop** when the server receives a request I identified *sometimes* **gunicorn** workers entering in `Uninterruptible Sleep (D) State` and then coming back.

Putting all together I suspect that is something related to [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask-caching) package  and specially the [FileSystemCache](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#filesystemcache) option. Since trying 'SimpleCache' cache option the problem disappeared [(but cache doesn't really work with **Gunicorn** multiple workers)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32149736/1207193).

For now my app.config is like bellow (worked flawlessly on the other ubuntu-server):

```
app.config['CACHE_DIR'] = 'cache' 
app.config['CACHE_TYPE'] = 'FileSystemCache' 
app.config['CACHE_THRESHOLD'] = 10000
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 300
```

I hope someone can point what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have a definitive answer. Still I'm posting what works in case is useful for someone else.

It seams it's a permission issue somehow so I changed the cache dir to `tmp` and my config became:

```
app.config['CACHE_DIR'] = '/tmp/my_site_cache/' 
app.config['CACHE_TYPE'] = 'FileSystemCache' 
app.config['CACHE_THRESHOLD'] = 10000
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 300
```

So far no more 10 or so seconds of Time To First Byte (TTFB).